# SQL query for highest score and latest date combined

Tags: sql

I have an SQL query that queryies a table that holds test scores

the table is set up as follows an `ID`(which is the Primary Key), `Username`, `UserID`, `Test_name`, `Date_Taken`, `Time_Taken`, `Num_questions`, `Grade`, `Time_Per_questionand`, `Test_Slug`.

I have the following SQL query that gives me the max score per test name for a specific user:

```
SELECT t.ID, 
       t.test_Name, 
       t.UserID, 
       t.Test_Slug, 
       t.Grade, 
       t.date_taken 
FROM   academytestsite.testscores t 
       JOIN (SELECT hs.test_Name, 
                    hs.UserID, 
                    hs.test_Slug, 
                    Max(hs.Grade) AS MaxGrade 
             FROM   academytestsite.testscores hs 
             GROUP  BY hs.test_Name, 
                       hs.UserID) mhs 
         ON mhs.test_Name = t.test_Name 
            AND mhs.UserID = t.UserID 
            AND mhs.MaxGrade = t.Grade 
WHERE  t.UserID = 5608 
ORDER  BY test_name
```

The problem i have is if the user has multiple `Grades` that are the same for the same test.

I want the query to only give the newest `Grade` whereas the statement gives all results that are the same. Hope this makes sense

I have tried grouping by `test_name` but this gives the first result per test in the table and not the newest.

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by rdnms it querying a MySQL database

Comment: That's what he meant. RDBMS stands for Relataional Database Management System, e.g. MySQL, Postgres, MS SQL, etc. They all have slightly different dialects of the SQL language, so it impacts the answer.

Comment: Order by datee_taken still give multiple results for the same score and grouping by score reduces to on line but it does not show the newest reult just the first in the database incase anone says try that

Comment: Thanks Dan, thought that might be what he wanted to know

Comment: Are you looking for the newest grade for each test, or the newest copy of the highest grade for each test?

Answer (score 3):

Most SQL dialects, MySQL included, lack any way of directly saying "give me the best row for each value of a particular column". The other answers posted both give you a way to say "give me a row for each value of a particular column where other columns equal the best." You can also say "give me each row where no better rows exist," which is what I've done below.

The technique for this is to use a `LEFT JOIN` to find better rows, and then use a `WHERE` clause to only select rows where the better rows' ID is NULL.

```
SELECT t.ID, 
       t.test_Name, 
       t.UserID, 
       t.Test_Slug, 
       t.Grade, 
       t.date_taken 
FROM   academytestsite.testscores t
LEFT JOIN academytestsite.testscores better_row
       ON better_row.test_Name = t.test_Name
      AND better_row.UserID = t.UserID
      AND (better_row.Grade > t.Grade
           OR (better_row.Grade = t.Grade AND better_row.date_taken > t.date_taken))
WHERE better_row.ID IS NULL
```

This version will find each test score with the highest grade, using the `date_taken` column as a tiebreaker when two grades match. You can change the criteria for the "best" row by changing the join condition. For example, if you just wanted the most recent grade for each test, you could use

```
      AND better_row.date_taken > t.date_taken
```

If you get multiple results using this method, then you need to adjust the join condition such that only one row for each *(test_Name, UserID)* pair can be selected as the "best" one. If you have duplicate grades and dates, could achieve this by making the primary key a tie breaker:

```
       AND (better_row.Grade > t.Grade
           OR (better_row.Grade = t.Grade AND better_row.date_taken > t.date_taken)
           OR (better_row.Grade = t.Grade AND better_row.date_taken = t.date_taken 
               AND better_row.ID > t.Id))
```

Comment: The query will not result the correct output! see [the sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8de9a/2)

Comment: Tried this with my database and it work, many thanks Dan for this awesome bit of code all i had to do was add the WHERE Useris="5608" part

Comment: It doesn't work with the fiddle posted by @MohsenHeydari because it assumes each user has a unique ID, and in the fiddle's sample data, all `UserId=1`. Here's the same fiddle with unique `UserId` values: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf7d9/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM academytestsite.testscores t 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT 
      UserID, 
      test_Name, 
      MAX(date_taken) as date_taken
   FROM academytestsite.testscores
   GROUP BY UserID, test_Name
) mhs ON (mhs.UserID = t.UserID) 
     AND (mhs.test_Name = t.test_Name) 
     AND (mhs.date_taken = t.date_taken)
ORDER BY t.test_Name
```

See [SQL demo](http://rextester.com/SQJ21107)

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
select grade, username, date_taken, time_taken from(
select grade, username, date_taken, time_taken from test_scores a
where a.grade = (select max(grade) from test_scores b where b.username = a.username group by username)
order by date_taken desc, time_taken desc) temp
group by username;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/550d7b/3

Answer (score 0):

To get the highest grade per user and test, you may use a self left join

```
select t1.* from testscores t1
left join testscores t2 on
t1.Username = t2.Username
and 
t1.test_name = t2.test_name
and t1.grade < t2.grade 
where t2.id is null
ORDER  BY t1.test_name
```

To get the newest taken date in a duplicate same grade, a MAX sub query will be helpful

```
select t1.* from testscores t1
left join testscores t2 on
t1.Username = t2.Username
and 
t1.test_name = t2.test_name
and t1.grade < t2.grade 
where t2.id is null
and t1.Date_Taken = 
    (select max(t3.Date_Taken) 
     from testscores t3 
     where t3.Username = t1.Username 
     and t3.test_name = t1.test_name 
     and t3.grade = t1.grade
     group by t3.Username , t3.test_name
     )
ORDER  BY t1.test_name
```

For performance reasons, you may also see `distinct` result, if just user, test and grade matters:

```
select distinct t1.Username , t1.test_name , t1.Grade from testscores t1
left join testscores t2 on
t1.Username = t2.Username
and 
t1.test_name = t2.test_name
and t1.grade < t2.grade 
where t2.id is null
ORDER  BY t1.test_name
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4604a/10)**